# Controller and action are getting remove from url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

When redirect to my application controller and action name is getting remove but query string is remain same 
request url
 http://example.com/Search/MyGResponse?guid=0136240964447518&UserId=PAYID-LTISIJQ9GD76314CR034732S&token=EC-6LN3872092121462M&PayerID=LGRA7HD7VFXHC

response url
http://example.com/?guid=0136240964447518&UserId=PAYID-LTISIJQ9GD76314CR034732S&token=EC-6LN3872092121462M&PayerID=LGRA7HD7VFXHC

Below is the code written for routing  public static void

```
RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/undefined");
            // BotDetect requests must not be routed
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*botdetect}",
              new { botdetect = @"(.*)BotDetectCaptcha\.ashx" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Redirected how? Post the code

Comment: Can you post your code. How do you configure your Routing config for your application.?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/

Comment: I have added the routing code. Please have a look. let me know if I am missing something.